# Cannot gain networking access in CentOS 6.2 installed on Hyper-V

Tags: centos, hyper-v, windows-server-2012-r2, vmware-workstation

Im trying to test a few pieces of software on a CentOS 6.2 VM installed in Hyper-V on Windows Server 2012 R2. I was able to successfully install CentOS 6.2 in Hyper-V but I am unable to gain access to the internet. If checked the following:

-Running `ifconfig` and `ifconfig -a` on lists the default `lo`

-The file `ifcfg-eth0` does not exist on a fresh install (it did exist when I installed CentOS on environments outside of Hyper-V). Creating this file and adding the required contents does not help. Neither ifdown nor ifup will work on eth0 once I create the file. Specifically, it complains that the "directory or file" does not exist.

-The file `70-persistent-net.rules` located under `/etc/udev/rules.d/` doesn't exist either. I also tried creating the file as well as adding the required contents to it for eth0 and it did not help. As I understand, this file should be automatically regenerated on system start up. It never gets created, no matter how many times the VM is started/restarted. I've looked up a few commands (that I no longer remember) to try to manually force the file to be regenerated. These commands were also unsuccessful.

I should note that I am running the Windows Server as a VM itself within VMware Workstation since our company wants to test and see if the software will work before purchasing the actual software.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Why are you using an out of date version of CentOS?

Comment: The software is currently stable on versions of CentOS up to 6.2

Comment: You should have the software fixed, then. You're going to be three years out of date on security and critical patches.

Answer (score 1):

RHEL/CentOS did not include the Hyper-V network drivers [until 6.4](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn531026.aspx). You should first start with the latest service pack if at all possible (currently 6.6) and test your software with it.

If you're certain you can't update, you need to install the [Linux Integration Services](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=41554), which provides out of tree network drivers.

Answer (score -1):

For anyone with a similar issue in the future, I found that following the steps in the following guide solved the problem:

http://blog.earth-works.com/2013/04/12/how-to-get-networking-working-in-centos-under-hyper-v/